# PHP PDO Json doesnt show in React Native

Tags: php, json, react-native, pdo

im trying to learn React native and started with a simple fetch of some data in simple app view.
I have a phpfile on my server which return some data in a Json (its an array with 3 Objs in it)

If i echo the php file i get a valid Json format and can see all the data on the browser.

But if i try to fetch the data over React Native i get a blank page.

Here is my PHPfile

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

try {
   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=foo', $user, $pass,
   [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"]
 );
 $query = "SELECT * FROM wochenplan_aufräumen";

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
 $result = array();
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     echo json_encode($result);
     return json_encode($result);


} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
?>
```

and here is my here is my react native component

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('foo.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

      })
        .then((response) => response.json)
        .then((json) => setData(json.id))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);

    console.log(data);

    return (

      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>

        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.crdate}, {item.crdate}</Text>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
}
```

Very strage is that the console.log(data); gives me one empty array and 2 others are undefined

Comment: Isn't `response.json()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some characters in your json-response that are not compatible to the json-format. Check if you have some linebreak's or spaces before and after.

Remove the line `return json_encode(...)` in the php-code if you don't use a function or class-method.

Have fun while learning react-native ;)

Answer (score 0):

With fetch, you parse the response to json by calling the `json()` method of the response.

```
fetch (/* ... */)
.then(response => response.json()) // here
.then(json => {})
```